# formating json data. how to merge json array with same value as key?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

sorry if my question is little confusing.
the following is my json output form mysql:

```
[{"ID":"2","BatchID":"0","Day":"Sunday","Low":"01:15","High":"02.45","Mid":    "01:30 01:45 02:00 02:15 02:30"},    {"ID":"1","BatchID":"0","Day":"Sunday","Low":"00.45","High":"00:30","Mid":"    01:30 01:45 02:00 02:15 02:30"}]
```

i want to use the day "sunday" in this case to merge both the objects to form something like this:

```
"Sunday":[
        {
            "low":"00:15",
            "high":"00.45",
            "mid":["00:30"]
        },
        {
            "low":"01:15",
            "high":"02.45",
            "mid":["01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30"]
        }

    ]
```

also, are there any tools that can help me make models in php for saving this in a db?

thanks in advance.

max

Comment: ps: my php object looks like this : Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2 [BatchID] => 0 [Day] => Sunday [Low] => 01:15 [High] => 02.45 [Mid] => 01:30 01:45 02:00 02:15 02:30 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [BatchID] => 0 [Day] => Sunday [Low] => 00.45 [High] => 00:30 [Mid] => 01:30 01:45 02:00 02:15 02:30 ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like :

```
$data = json_decode($mysql_data, true);
$res = [];
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    $add = ['low'  => $d['Low'],
            'high' => $d['High'],
            'mid'  => explode(' ', trim($d['Mid']))];
    if (!isset($res[$d['Day']]))
        $res[$d['Day']] = $add;
    else
        $res[$d['Day']][] = $add;
}
$pretty_data = json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Thank you Ebahi, you saved my entire night! :)) i removed the condition and it works like a charm ;) /*
    if (!isset($res[$d['Day']]))
        $res[$d['Day']] = $add;
    else
*/

Answer (score 1):

You can reorganize it in PHP as the other answer suggests. You can also reorganize it in Javascript:

```
var values = [{"ID":"2","BatchID":"0","Day":"Sunday","Low":"01:15","High":"02.45","Mid":    "01:30 01:45 02:00 02:15 02:30"},    {"ID":"1","BatchID":"0","Day":"Sunday","Low":"00.45","High":"00:30","Mid":"    01:30 01:45 02:00 02:15 02:30"}];

var final = {};
values.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if (!final[element.Day]) 
        final[element.Day] = [];

    final[element.Day].push(
        {
            "low": element.Low,
            "high": element.High,
            "mid": element.Mid.split(" ")
        }
    );
});
```